# write the results of for loop to csv in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, gate

currently I am using Groovy to create nested for loops that print the contents of objects to a string intended to be rows of delimited data. I would like to output these strings to a csv file however rather than printing them.

Here is the code:

```
for (doc in docs) {
    AnnotationSet row = doc.getAnnotations("Final").get("Row")
    AnnotationSet BondCounsel = doc.getAnnotations("Final").get("Bond_Counsel")
    AnnotationSet PurchasePrice = doc.getAnnotations("Final").get("PurchasePrice")
    AnnotationSet DiscountRate = doc.getAnnotations("Final").get("DiscountRate")
    for (b in BondCounsel) {
        for (d in DiscountRate) {
            for (r in row) {
                for (p in PurchasePrice) {
    println(doc.getFeatures().get("gate.SourceURL") + "|"
    + "mat_amount|" + r.getFeatures().get("MatAmount") + "|"
    + "orig_price|" + p.getFeatures().get("VAL") + "|"
    + "orig_yield|" + r.getFeatures().get("Yield") + "|"
    + "orig_discount_rate|" + d.getFeatures().get("rate")+ "|"
    + "CUSIP|" + r.getFeatures().get("CUSIPVAL1") + r.getFeatures().get("CUSIPVAL2") + r.getFeatures().get("CUSIPVAL3") + "|"
    + "Bond_Counsel|" + b.getFeatures().get("value"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where the output are just a series of strings such as:

```
filename1|mat_amt|3|orig_price|$230,000.....
filename2|mat_amt|4|orig_price|$380,000.....
```

I understand I can set up a file writer i.e.

```
fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, csvFileFormat);
csvFilePrinter.printRecord(FILE_HEADER);

<for loop here storing results>
csvFilePrinter.printRecord(forLoopResults)
```

But I am unsure how to properly format and store what I currently printing in the for loop to be able to pass onto `csvFilePrinter.printRecord()`

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `printRecord()` method takes an Iterable (per [doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.html)). e.g. a list.

So in the inner loop of your code, rather than print, we would create a list for that row.

Specifically, given this setup:

```
def FILE_HEADER = ['Bond','Discount','Row','Price']    
def fileName = 'out.csv'
```

and this data aggregation (as an example):

```
def BondCounsel = ['bc1','bc2']
def DiscountRate = ['0.1','0.2']
def row = ['r1','r2']
def PurchasePrice = ['p1','p2']
```

then this (**edit**: now made Groovier):

```
new File(fileName).withWriter { fileWriter ->
    def csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, CSVFormat.DEFAULT)
    csvFilePrinter.printRecord(FILE_HEADER)

    BondCounsel.each { b ->
        DiscountRate.each { d ->
            row.each { r ->
                PurchasePrice.each { p ->
                    csvFilePrinter.printRecord([b, d, r, p])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

would generate this to `out.csv`:

```
Bond,Discount,Row,Price
bc1,0.1,r1,p1
bc1,0.1,r1,p2
bc1,0.1,r2,p1
... etc
```

Comment: Hi Michael - thanks very much for this and for the explanation

Comment: Don't you think that the `rows` variable is unnecessary? I would print the row directly: `csvFilePrinter.printRecord([b, d, r, p])`

Comment: @dedek fair point. I have updated the answer to make it Groovier.